Is the probability that the sum of random integers is divisible by $k$ equal to $1/k$?

There are $n$ cards which have numbers $1$~$n$ on each. You pick $m$ cards from it, and you don't put it back once you pick from it. Is the probability that their sum is divisible by $k$ always $\dfrac 1 k$, while $k|n$? If not, how do we generalize the probability?

I've tried to look for the counterexample and found when $n=6, m=3, k=3$. Since the number of cases is $20$, it isn't divisible by 3, so the probability cannot be $\dfrac 1 3$.
Then my question goes,

If not, how do we generalize the probability?

I've tried solving this with a multinomial, but this way, we can't exclude the condition that we don't put it back. (Multinomials should be about independent probabilities, so that's the reason for them, too.)
I tried solving this with Python and found some examples:
Picking 1 card from 1 card - divisible by 1: 1.0

Picking 2 cards from 2 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0

Picking 2 cards from 3 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 2 cards from 3 cards - divisible by 3: 0.3333333333333333

Picking 3 cards from 4 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 3 cards from 4 cards - divisible by 2: 0.5
Picking 3 cards from 4 cards - divisible by 4: 0.25

Picking 3 cards from 5 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 3 cards from 5 cards - divisible by 5: 0.2

Picking 4 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 4 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 2: 0.6
Picking 4 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 3: 0.3333333333333333
Picking 4 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 6: 0.2

Picking 4 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 4 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 7: 0.14285714285714285

Picking 5 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 5 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 2: 0.5
Picking 5 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 4: 0.25
Picking 5 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 8: 0.125

Picking 5 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 5 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 3: 0.3333333333333333
Picking 5 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 9: 0.1111111111111111

Picking 6 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 6 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 2: 0.47619047619047616
Picking 6 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 5: 0.2
Picking 6 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 10: 0.09523809523809523

Then I found that for prime $p$, $p^n$ has a pattern: $1, 1/p, 1/p^2, \cdots$.
Now I can't find more patterns from this... Any help will be appreciated.
Edit. I decided to try some more, and I got:
Picking 1 card from 1 card - divisible by 1: 1.0


Picking 1 card from 2 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 2 cards from 2 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0

Picking 1 card from 2 cards - divisible by 2: 0.5
Picking 2 cards from 2 cards - divisible by 2: 0.0


Picking 1 card from 3 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 2 cards from 3 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 3 cards from 3 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0

Picking 1 cards from 3 cards - divisible by 2: 0
Picking 2 cards from 3 cards - divisible by 2: 0
Picking 3 cards from 3 cards - divisible by 2: 0

Picking 1 card from 3 cards - divisible by 3: 0.3333333333333333
Picking 2 cards from 3 cards - divisible by 3: 0.3333333333333333
Picking 3 cards from 3 cards - divisible by 3: 1.0


Picking 1 cards from 4 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 2 cards from 4 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 3 cards from 4 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 4 cards from 4 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0

Picking 1 card from 4 cards - divisible by 2: 0.5
Picking 2 cards from 4 cards - divisible by 2: 0.3333333333333333
Picking 3 cards from 4 cards - divisible by 2: 0.5
Picking 4 cards from 4 cards - divisible by 2: 1.0

Picking 1 cards from 4 cards - divisible by 3: 0
Picking 2 cards from 4 cards - divisible by 3: 0
Picking 3 cards from 4 cards - divisible by 3: 0
Picking 4 cards from 4 cards - divisible by 3: 0

Picking 1 card from 4 cards - divisible by 4: 0.25
Picking 2 cards from 4 cards - divisible by 4: 0.16666666666666666
Picking 3 cards from 4 cards - divisible by 4: 0.25
Picking 4 cards from 4 cards - divisible by 4: 0.0


Picking 1 cards from 5 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 2 cards from 5 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 3 cards from 5 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 4 cards from 5 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 5 cards from 5 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0

Picking 1 cards from 5 cards - divisible by 2: 0
Picking 2 cards from 5 cards - divisible by 2: 0
Picking 3 cards from 5 cards - divisible by 2: 0
Picking 4 cards from 5 cards - divisible by 2: 0
Picking 5 cards from 5 cards - divisible by 2: 0

Picking 1 cards from 5 cards - divisible by 3: 0
Picking 2 cards from 5 cards - divisible by 3: 0
Picking 3 cards from 5 cards - divisible by 3: 0
Picking 4 cards from 5 cards - divisible by 3: 0
Picking 5 cards from 5 cards - divisible by 3: 0

Picking 1 cards from 5 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 2 cards from 5 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 3 cards from 5 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 4 cards from 5 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 5 cards from 5 cards - divisible by 4: 0

Picking 1 card from 5 cards - divisible by 5: 0.2
Picking 2 cards from 5 cards - divisible by 5: 0.2
Picking 3 cards from 5 cards - divisible by 5: 0.2
Picking 4 cards from 5 cards - divisible by 5: 0.2
Picking 5 cards from 5 cards - divisible by 5: 1.0


Picking 1 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 2 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 3 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 4 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 5 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 6 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0

Picking 1 card from 6 cards - divisible by 2: 0.5
Picking 2 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 2: 0.4
Picking 3 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 2: 0.5
Picking 4 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 2: 0.6
Picking 5 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 2: 0.5
Picking 6 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 2: 0.0

Picking 1 card from 6 cards - divisible by 3: 0.3333333333333333
Picking 2 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 3: 0.3333333333333333
Picking 3 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 3: 0.4
Picking 4 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 3: 0.3333333333333333
Picking 5 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 3: 0.3333333333333333
Picking 6 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 3: 1.0

Picking 1 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 2 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 3 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 4 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 5 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 6 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 4: 0

Picking 1 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 5: 0
Picking 2 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 5: 0
Picking 3 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 5: 0
Picking 4 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 5: 0
Picking 5 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 5: 0
Picking 6 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 5: 0

Picking 1 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 6: 0.16666666666666666
Picking 2 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 6: 0.13333333333333333
Picking 3 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 6: 0.2
Picking 4 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 6: 0.2
Picking 5 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 6: 0.16666666666666666
Picking 6 cards from 6 cards - divisible by 6: 0.0


Picking 1 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 2 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 3 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 4 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 5 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 6 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 7 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0

Picking 1 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 2: 0
Picking 2 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 2: 0
Picking 3 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 2: 0
Picking 4 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 2: 0
Picking 5 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 2: 0
Picking 6 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 2: 0
Picking 7 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 2: 0

Picking 1 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 3: 0
Picking 2 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 3: 0
Picking 3 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 3: 0
Picking 4 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 3: 0
Picking 5 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 3: 0
Picking 6 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 3: 0
Picking 7 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 3: 0

Picking 1 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 2 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 3 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 4 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 5 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 6 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 7 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 4: 0

Picking 1 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 5: 0
Picking 2 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 5: 0
Picking 3 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 5: 0
Picking 4 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 5: 0
Picking 5 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 5: 0
Picking 6 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 5: 0
Picking 7 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 5: 0

Picking 1 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 6: 0
Picking 2 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 6: 0
Picking 3 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 6: 0
Picking 4 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 6: 0
Picking 5 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 6: 0
Picking 6 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 6: 0
Picking 7 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 6: 0

Picking 1 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 7: 0.14285714285714285
Picking 2 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 7: 0.14285714285714285
Picking 3 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 7: 0.14285714285714285
Picking 4 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 7: 0.14285714285714285
Picking 5 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 7: 0.14285714285714285
Picking 6 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 7: 0.14285714285714285
Picking 7 cards from 7 cards - divisible by 7: 1.0


Picking 1 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 2 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 3 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 4 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 5 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 6 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 7 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 8 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0

Picking 1 card from 8 cards - divisible by 2: 0.5
Picking 2 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 2: 0.42857142857142855
Picking 3 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 2: 0.5
Picking 4 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 2: 0.5428571428571428
Picking 5 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 2: 0.5
Picking 6 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 2: 0.42857142857142855
Picking 7 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 2: 0.5
Picking 8 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 2: 1.0

Picking 1 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 3: 0
Picking 2 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 3: 0
Picking 3 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 3: 0
Picking 4 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 3: 0
Picking 5 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 3: 0
Picking 6 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 3: 0
Picking 7 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 3: 0
Picking 8 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 3: 0

Picking 1 card from 8 cards - divisible by 4: 0.25
Picking 2 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 4: 0.21428571428571427
Picking 3 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 4: 0.25
Picking 4 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 4: 0.2571428571428571
Picking 5 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 4: 0.25
Picking 6 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 4: 0.21428571428571427
Picking 7 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 4: 0.25
Picking 8 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 4: 1.0

Picking 1 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 5: 0
Picking 2 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 5: 0
Picking 3 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 5: 0
Picking 4 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 5: 0
Picking 5 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 5: 0
Picking 6 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 5: 0
Picking 7 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 5: 0
Picking 8 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 5: 0

Picking 1 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 6: 0
Picking 2 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 6: 0
Picking 3 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 6: 0
Picking 4 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 6: 0
Picking 5 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 6: 0
Picking 6 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 6: 0
Picking 7 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 6: 0
Picking 8 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 6: 0

Picking 1 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 7: 0
Picking 2 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 7: 0
Picking 3 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 7: 0
Picking 4 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 7: 0
Picking 5 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 7: 0
Picking 6 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 7: 0
Picking 7 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 7: 0
Picking 8 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 7: 0

Picking 1 card from 8 cards - divisible by 8: 0.125
Picking 2 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 8: 0.10714285714285714
Picking 3 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 8: 0.125
Picking 4 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 8: 0.12857142857142856
Picking 5 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 8: 0.125
Picking 6 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 8: 0.10714285714285714
Picking 7 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 8: 0.125
Picking 8 cards from 8 cards - divisible by 8: 0.0


Picking 1 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 2 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 3 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 4 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 5 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 6 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 7 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 8 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 9 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0

Picking 1 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 2: 0
Picking 2 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 2: 0
Picking 3 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 2: 0
Picking 4 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 2: 0
Picking 5 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 2: 0
Picking 6 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 2: 0
Picking 7 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 2: 0
Picking 8 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 2: 0
Picking 9 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 2: 0

Picking 1 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 3: 0.3333333333333333
Picking 2 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 3: 0.3333333333333333
Picking 3 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 3: 0.35714285714285715
Picking 4 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 3: 0.3333333333333333
Picking 5 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 3: 0.3333333333333333
Picking 6 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 3: 0.35714285714285715
Picking 7 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 3: 0.3333333333333333
Picking 8 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 3: 0.3333333333333333
Picking 9 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 3: 1.0

Picking 1 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 2 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 3 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 4 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 5 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 6 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 7 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 8 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 9 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 4: 0

Picking 1 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 5: 0
Picking 2 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 5: 0
Picking 3 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 5: 0
Picking 4 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 5: 0
Picking 5 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 5: 0
Picking 6 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 5: 0
Picking 7 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 5: 0
Picking 8 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 5: 0
Picking 9 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 5: 0

Picking 1 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 6: 0
Picking 2 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 6: 0
Picking 3 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 6: 0
Picking 4 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 6: 0
Picking 5 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 6: 0
Picking 6 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 6: 0
Picking 7 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 6: 0
Picking 8 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 6: 0
Picking 9 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 6: 0

Picking 1 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 7: 0
Picking 2 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 7: 0
Picking 3 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 7: 0
Picking 4 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 7: 0
Picking 5 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 7: 0
Picking 6 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 7: 0
Picking 7 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 7: 0
Picking 8 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 7: 0
Picking 9 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 7: 0

Picking 1 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 8: 0
Picking 2 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 8: 0
Picking 3 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 8: 0
Picking 4 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 8: 0
Picking 5 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 8: 0
Picking 6 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 8: 0
Picking 7 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 8: 0
Picking 8 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 8: 0
Picking 9 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 8: 0

Picking 1 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 9: 0.1111111111111111
Picking 2 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 9: 0.1111111111111111
Picking 3 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 9: 0.11904761904761904
Picking 4 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 9: 0.1111111111111111
Picking 5 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 9: 0.1111111111111111
Picking 6 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 9: 0.11904761904761904
Picking 7 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 9: 0.1111111111111111
Picking 8 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 9: 0.1111111111111111
Picking 9 cards from 9 cards - divisible by 9: 1.0


Picking 1 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 2 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 3 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 4 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 5 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 6 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 7 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 8 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 9 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0
Picking 10 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 1: 1.0

Picking 1 card from 10 cards - divisible by 2: 0.5
Picking 2 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 2: 0.4444444444444444
Picking 3 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 2: 0.5
Picking 4 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 2: 0.5238095238095238
Picking 5 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 2: 0.5
Picking 6 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 2: 0.47619047619047616
Picking 7 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 2: 0.5
Picking 8 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 2: 0.5555555555555556
Picking 9 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 2: 0.5
Picking 10 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 2: 0.0

Picking 1 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 3: 0
Picking 2 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 3: 0
Picking 3 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 3: 0
Picking 4 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 3: 0
Picking 5 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 3: 0
Picking 6 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 3: 0
Picking 7 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 3: 0
Picking 8 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 3: 0
Picking 9 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 3: 0
Picking 10 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 3: 0

Picking 1 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 2 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 3 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 4 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 5 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 6 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 7 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 8 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 9 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 4: 0
Picking 10 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 4: 0

Picking 1 card from 10 cards - divisible by 5: 0.2
Picking 2 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 5: 0.2
Picking 3 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 5: 0.2
Picking 4 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 5: 0.2
Picking 5 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 5: 0.20634920634920634
Picking 6 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 5: 0.2
Picking 7 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 5: 0.2
Picking 8 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 5: 0.2
Picking 9 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 5: 0.2
Picking 10 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 5: 1.0

Picking 1 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 6: 0
Picking 2 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 6: 0
Picking 3 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 6: 0
Picking 4 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 6: 0
Picking 5 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 6: 0
Picking 6 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 6: 0
Picking 7 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 6: 0
Picking 8 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 6: 0
Picking 9 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 6: 0
Picking 10 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 6: 0

Picking 1 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 7: 0
Picking 2 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 7: 0
Picking 3 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 7: 0
Picking 4 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 7: 0
Picking 5 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 7: 0
Picking 6 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 7: 0
Picking 7 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 7: 0
Picking 8 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 7: 0
Picking 9 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 7: 0
Picking 10 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 7: 0

Picking 1 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 8: 0
Picking 2 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 8: 0
Picking 3 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 8: 0
Picking 4 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 8: 0
Picking 5 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 8: 0
Picking 6 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 8: 0
Picking 7 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 8: 0
Picking 8 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 8: 0
Picking 9 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 8: 0
Picking 10 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 8: 0

Picking 1 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 9: 0
Picking 2 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 9: 0
Picking 3 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 9: 0
Picking 4 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 9: 0
Picking 5 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 9: 0
Picking 6 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 9: 0
Picking 7 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 9: 0
Picking 8 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 9: 0
Picking 9 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 9: 0
Picking 10 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 9: 0

Picking 1 card from 10 cards - divisible by 10: 0.1
Picking 2 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 10: 0.08888888888888889
Picking 3 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 10: 0.1
Picking 4 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 10: 0.10476190476190476
Picking 5 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 10: 0.10317460317460317
Picking 6 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 10: 0.09523809523809523
Picking 7 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 10: 0.1
Picking 8 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 10: 0.1111111111111111
Picking 9 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 10: 0.1
Picking 10 cards from 10 cards - divisible by 10: 0.0

Well, now I see that(as in the answer below) most of them are the value of $\dfrac 1 k$. Now again my question focuses on:

When do the exceptions occur? For the exceptions, how to treat them?

Edit 2. I plotted a graph, with $n$ in the $x$-axis and the probability in the $y$-axis.

What can we get from this? I did this because it seems to need a visualization to solve this.

Do you require $k\mid n$?

@RosieF If we dont have that $n$ is divisible by $k$, then the property is not true for $m=1$. You could extend the idea I offer in my solution but it would get very ugly.

This was a beautiful problem to solve. Thank you very much. I have a complete solution, but I strongly encourage everyone to try to solve it on their own. If you wish to do so, leave now or read the "key observation" below if you want a hint.
I have written two detailed posts on my blog in which I go into more details:

A simulation study

A detailed mathematical analysis with the final result



The key observation
The key observation is due to @Matthew Spam.

Going from a given a subset $(x_1 \dots x_m)$ to the subset $(x_1 + i \dots x_m + i)$ shifts the final result by $m * i \bmod k$. Thus, we can reach all values that are offset from the initial result by $\operatorname{gcd}(m, k)$.

Again, it is really worth to try to solve this problem by yourself. Trying to figure out how to use this fact is really instructive.

Answer: a sufficient condition for $p=1/k$
When $\operatorname{gcd}(m, k) = 1$, the probability is $p=1/k$.
Proof: the observation by Matthew is already sufficient to conclude. It shows that the number of subsets summing to any value in $[0, k-1]$ is equal: i.e. the distribution of $\sum X_i \bmod k$ is uniform.
Is the condition necessary
Yes, sort of. When the gcd is not $1$, the probability can be explicitly computed. It's a bit simpler than proposed by @user2661923 because we do not need to look at every single case like they proposed.
I won't deal with the most general case here: please refer to my blog post; I hope it does a good-enough job because this is a complex solution.
Let's focus on the case where $k$ is prime and $\geq 3$.
A simple case
The values can be decomposed into $n/k$ groups. Let $c_i$ be the count of values in the i-th group. We will compute the desired probability conditional on the $c_i$.

If any $c_i$ is $1$, then conditionally $p=1/k$.

Proof: repeat the symmetry argument, but this time only shifting the value $x_i$ inside of its group. This shifts the final sum by $1$, giving us the symmetry.
This is not the most generic case.


If $\operatorname{gcd}(k, c_1, c_2 \dots) = 1$, then conditionally $p=1/k$. NB: excluding 0 counts.

Proof: repeat the symmetry argument: shift each value inside of its own group. This modifies the sum by adding $c_1 * i_1 + c_2 * i_2 + \dots$. By definition of the gcd, we can reach any value.


When does the condition $\operatorname{gcd}(k, c_1, c_2 \dots) = 1$ not occur? When all counts are either $0$ or $k$.

In this situation, there is no randomness left. The sum is simply: $k (k-1) / 2 * n / k$. This is divisible by $k$ thus, conditionally $p=1$.



We can now conclude:

Conditional on the event $A$: "all counts are exactly $k$", $p=1$.
Else, $p=1/k$.

Thus, the unconditional probability is such that: $p > 1/k$. The offset depends on the probability of the event $A$ which goes to $0$ as $n$ grows.
$$
p = p(A) + (1-p(A)) \frac{1}{k} = \frac{1}{k} + p(A) \frac{k-1}{k}
$$

Wow. First, thanks for your commitment to my post. Since your posts have a lot of texts to read, it may take some time for me. (I’m not the native American or English-fluent.) I’ll be back when I finish reading all your posts! Again, thanks for your answers.

I’m back, thanks for the generalization! Your conjecture, analysis, and solution are fully elegant.

Thank you very much for sharing this. I was really happy to work on it: it's a really interesting case to consider.

Not an immediate answer, but an interesting observation: if $\operatorname{gcd}(m,n)=1$ then the probability is equal to $\frac{1}{k}$.
This can be seen as follows. Suppose we have any subset $S=\{s_1,s_2, \ldots, s_m\}$. Consider the subsets $S_i=\{(s_1+i)\mod n, (s_2+i)\mod n, \ldots, (s_m+i)\mod n\}$ for $i=1,2,\ldots, n-1,n$. The sums of the elements of $S_i$ are all distinct modulo $n$ for different $i$ because $\operatorname{gcd}(m,n)=1$.
It follows that we can divide the subsets of size $m$ into groups of $n$ subsets each, where each modulo occurs once in each group. So we have the same probability of getting a sum of $i\mod n$ for each $i$, and therefore a probability of $\frac{1}{k}$ to be divisible by $k$ if $k|n$.

Interesting! That’s why I got the pattern I mentioned in the post. Thanks for the partial answer!

Hello Matthew. Your observation is almost enough to find the sufficient and necessary condition for $p=1/k$. See my answer here which builds upon your initial insight: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/5013002/251691 Thank you very much for sharing this. It was a key step to solving the problem for me.

By my analysis, a closed form formula is feasible.  However, the math that I derived is very ugly.  It will be interesting to see if someone can come up with a more elegant closed form formula.
For what it's worth, this answer does not require that $~n~$ be a multiple of $~k.$
For ease of syntax, this answer adopts the convention that when $~a < b,~$ that $~\displaystyle \binom{a}{b} = 0.$
Label the cards, so that $~C_i~$ denotes the card with the number $~i~$ on it, where $~i \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\}.~$
Assume that the $~m~$ cards selected are specifically the cards $~C_{x_1}, ~C_{x_2}, ~\cdots, ~C_{x_m},~$ where $~x_1, ~x_2, \cdots, x_m~$ are distinct elements in $~\{1,2,\cdots,n\},~$ which are in strictly ascending order.
Then, a lower bound on $~\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^m x_i~$ is $~0,~$ and an upper bound on $~\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^m x_i~$ is
$$n + (n-1) + \cdots + (n+1-m) = nm - \frac{(m-1)m}{2} = \frac{m(2n+1-m)}{2}.$$
Let $~\lfloor u\rfloor~$ refer to the floor function, for $~u \in \Bbb{R}.$
Let $~\displaystyle A = \left\lfloor \frac{m(2n+1-m)}{2k} ~\right\rfloor.$
For $~r \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,A\},~$ let $~f(r)~$ denote the number of solutions to

$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_m = r \times k.$

$x_1, ~x_2, ~\cdots, ~x_m \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\}.$

$x_1, ~x_2, ~\cdots, ~x_m~$ are in strictly ascending order.


Then, the probability that $~m~$ numbers chosen at random (sampling without replacement) from $~\{1,2,\cdots,n\}~$ will have a sum divisible by $~k~$ is
$$\frac{\sum_{r = 0}^A f(r)}{\binom{n}{m}}. \tag1 $$
So, the entire problem reduces to computing $~f(r).~$  The chief difficulty here is that $~x_1, ~x_2, ~\cdots, ~x_m~$ must be distinct (and therefore in ascending order, rather than in non-decreasing order).

Personally, my knowledge of Combinatorics tools is very limited.  For example, I am ignorant about generating functions.  The only way that I know how to solve this is very ugly.
Let:

$y_1 = x_1.$

$y_{i+1} = x_{i+1} - x_i ~: ~i \in \{1,2,\cdots,m-1\}.$


Then, for $~i \in \{1,2,\cdots,m\},~$ you have that $~\displaystyle x_i = \sum_{a=1}^i y_a.$
Therefore, the enumeration of $~f(r)~$ has been transformed into enumerating the number of solutions to:

$~my_1 + (m-1)y_2 + \cdots + 2y_{m-1} + y_m = rk.$

$~y_1, ~y_2, ~\cdots, y_m \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}.$


The first thing to do is adjust each of the variables so that their lower bound is $~0,~$ rather than $~1.~$
So, $~f(r)~$ is the enumeration of the number of solutions to:

$~my_1 + (m-1)y_2 + \cdots + 2y_{m-1} + y_m = rk - \dfrac{m(m+1)}{2}.$

$~y_1, ~y_2, ~\cdots, y_m \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$


If $~rk - \dfrac{m(m+1)}{2} < 0,~$ then $~f(r) = 0.~$
So, you can assume, without loss of generality, that $~rk - \dfrac{m(m+1)}{2} \geq 0,~$ in which case the lower bound on each of $~y_1, ~y_2, ~\cdots, ~y_m~$ is $~0.$
Given any positive integers $~s,t~$ define $~\displaystyle g(s,t) = \left\lfloor \frac{s}{t} ~\right\rfloor.~$
Then, the upper bound for $~y_1~$ is
$~\displaystyle g\left( ~rk - \frac{m(m+1)}{2}, ~m ~\right).$
Assume that $~y_1~$ is any integer in the appropriate range.  Then, based on the specific value chosen for $~y_1,~$ the upper bound for $~y_2~$ is $~\displaystyle g\left( ~rk - \frac{m(m+1)}{2} - my_1, ~m-1 ~\right).$
Similarly, for $~p \in \{2,3,\cdots,m-1\},~$ assuming that the variables $~y_1, y_2, \cdots, y_{p-1}~$ are all integers in range, then the upper bound for $~y_p~$ is
$$g\left( rk - \frac{m(m+1)}{2} - \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} (m+1-i)y_i ~, ~~~~~~m+1-p ~\right).$$
Once $~y_1, ~y_2, \cdots, ~y_{m-1}~$ are chosen, then $~y_m~$ is determined.
So,
$$f(r) = \sum_{y_1 ~\text{in range}} ~\left\{ ~\sum_{y_2 ~\text{in range}} ~\left[ ~\sum_{y_3 ~\text{in range}} \cdots ~\left( ~\sum_{y_{(m-1)} ~\text{in range}} ~1 ~\right) ~\cdots ~\right] ~\right\}.$$

Obviously, the algorithm requires computer assistance to compute.  The corresponding computer program will be somewhat more complicated to program than just a simple $~m$-nested looping of $~x_1, ~\cdots, ~x_m~$ where you check each occurrence of $~\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^m x_i.~$
However, unless I am mistaken, the corresponding computer program will (in effect) be optimized.  That is, it will still feature $~(m-1)$-nested looping.  However, the range of each variable $~y_i~$ will be relatively limited, compared to the strategy in the previous paragraph.
Again assuming that I am not mistaken, this implies that on a vanilla personal computer, you can process significantly larger values of $~(n,m)~$ with the optimized algorithm than with the non-optimized algorithm.

Wow, firstly thanks for your effort! (+1) This does not give us an accurate solution but suggests the reasonable direction of the solution.

@RDK Why is the solution not accurate?

Well… what I’m looking for is an answer with the minimum of sigmas or something else that has some possibility to make it shorter. If there aren’t any other solutions, your solution would be accurate. :) Sorry if it felt like I underestimated your answer, I didn’t mean that.

Hey user2661923. I was able to find a general solution method. It builds upon your idea here by simplifying through many such cases. If you are interested check out https://math.stackexchange.com/a/5013002/251691 and my blog post https://www.guillaumedehaene.com/posts/2024/12/stack_overflow_1_k__2.html I did not try to find explicit formulas for the probability of the counts which would follow your answer, I think?

Here is a more intuitive outline for a proof.

The probability distribution of the sum of cards modulo $n$ has a periodic pattern with length $m$.
Outline of a proof: compare the sum of cards picked from cards 2 to n+1 and the sum for $m$ cards picked from 1 to n. Note that these cards are the same set modulo $n$. The distribution of the sum will be a shift by $k$. Yet modulo $k$ the distribution must be the same because if we compute a sum modulo $n$ then it doesn't matter when we first compute all the individual terms modulo $k$ (but if we apply modulo $k$ to the cards then we have the same sets). Therefore the distribution must have a cyclic pattern.
Example from a simulation with $n = 6$ and $m=3$


The probability distribution of the sum of cards modulo $k$ is uniform if $gcd(k,m) = 1$ and $k|n$ and $m|n$.
For each of the $k$ possible values for the sum modulo $k$, this will correspond to the entire cyclic pattern of length $m$ for which each vakue will be sampled $n/k/m$ times.
If the sum modulo $k$ equals $p$, then this corresponds to values for sum modulo $n$ of $ik + p$ with $i = 0,1,2\dots, n/k+1$. From these $n/k+1$ values the modulus of $m$ will be encounted the same number of times and it is like the average of the probabilities in the cyclic pattern.
For example with $n=6,m=3,k=2$ we have if the sum modulo $k=2$ equals $p=0$ the potential sum modulo $n$ values of 0, 2 ,4 and modulo $m=3$ those vakues will be $0,2,1$ which samples the entire cyclic pattern described in the previous point.


Therefore a sufficient condition is
$gcd(k,m) = 1$ and $k|n$ and $m|n$.
and more generally the probability for the sum modulo $k$ is uniform.

I believe that another sufficient condition is when $gcd(m,n) = 1$, in that case the distribution for the sum modulo $n$ will be continuous, and so will be the distribution the sum modulo $k$ if $k|n$.
